# Implicitly expose members of a class property

Tags: c#

I wonder if it's possible to access public members of a property of an object without specifying the name of the property.

Exemple :

```
// Bar.cs
public class Bar {
    public bool SomeMethod() {

    }
}

// Container.cs
public class Container<T> {
    public T Content;
}


// Anywhere.cs
Container<Bar> container;

// Is there a way to access Bar properties and method directly like this ?
container.SomeMethod();
// Instead of:
container.Content.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Foo only has one property -> Bar. Why would you think you could leave it out and call SomeProperty directly?

Comment: Maybe I should have explained this in my example, but Foo is generic and I don't know what Bar is.

Comment: @KevinM: I don't even know how to read that comment. It sounds like you should really put together a clearer example, otherwise we're going to have no chance of helping you.

Comment: @KevinM One reason I would think that this would not be possible would be, what if you added another property to Foo, say Bar2 and Bar2 has a property named SomeProperty, now you have two properties of Foo which have the same property name, how would it even  know which one to return?

Comment: I changed my exemple

Comment: `Container<T>` doesn't have any generic constraints, `T` can be any type, not the `Bar` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible option here is to apply a generic constraint to the `Container<T>` class using `where` keyword

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class Container<T> where T : Bar
{
    public T Content;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Content?.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Generic types are resolved at runtime, so you can't know what is the type `T` exactly and does it have `SomeMethod()` or not. You can create a base class or interface to use it as constraint instead of using `where T : Bar`.

Another option is cast `Content` to the concrete type (or use a reflection even), but you lose all benefits of generic types

```cs
public void SomeMethod()
{
    if (Content is Bar bar)
    {
        bar.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do a similar thing but without adding SomeMethod to Container. I guess what I want to acheive is just not possible and not a good idea.